# XML column in table with join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath

I've got a table with an xml column called `data` (xml has got `id` node) and second table with `idSecond` column.

I would like to perform join between these two tables so that `data[id] = secondTable.ID`

What would be the syntax for this in SQL Server 2005 ?

thanks for any hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`xml.value()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method to project the node id, then join on the projected value. Eg:

```
with x as (
select xmlcolumn.value(N'xquery_for_node...', N'type') as id,
   ...
from xmltable)
select ...
from x join secondtable on x.id = ...
```

Actual syntax and xquery used depends on the schema of your tables and the XML content. If there are multiple node ids to project then use [`xml.nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) in a [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) instead.